# Excel 2010: Formatting Header through VBA Script

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a VBA script that I've culled from the internet.  It takes the contents of a cell and puts it into the appropriate header.  This works exactly how I need it.

```
Sub InsertHeaderFooter()
' inserts the same header/footer in all worksheets
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Application.StatusBar = "Changing header/footer in " & ws.Name
        With ws.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = vbCr & vbCr & vbCr &B &9 & Range("J2").Text & vbCr & vbCr & Range("J3").Text & vbCr & Range("J4").Text & vbCr & Range("J5")
            .CenterHeader = vbCr & vbCr & vbCr & Range("J1").Text
        End With
    Next ws
    Set ws = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

The problem I have is formatting the header through the VBA script.  I found the [formatting documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822794%28v=office.14%29.aspx)  I don't know where to use the &B for bold or &nn for font-size in the script.  Every place I've put it, breaks the script.

Comment: I think the & is being treated like a concatenation. Have you tried:  vbCr & '&b' & '&9'. Double quotes might work if single ones don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line `.LeftHeader = ...` you basically provided Excel with a string.

In VBA, a stringmust be quoted with `"` unless it is an internal VB constant (e.g. `vbCr`) or a variable (e.g. `Range("J2").Text`).

Therefore, try this line:

```
 .LeftHeader = vbCr & vbCr & vbCr & "&B &9" & Range("J2").Text & vbCr & vbCr & Range("J3").Text & vbCr & Range("J4").Text & vbCr & Range("J5")
```

This will pass Excel a string that contains the enters, values from the ranges - and the text "&B &9" which Excel will parse as Bold and something else (don't know what the &9 stands for)

Comment: Peter,  thank you.  You're advice solved most of my problem.  I was about the pass "&B" into the string, but not the font size.  I think I have to pass the font name _then_ size in order for it to work.  But, thank you again.

Comment: The &9 is being used to specify font size of the header.  I learned that it must be in the beginning of the statement, like so `.LeftHeader = "&9" & ` , anywhere else, it was choking the script.

Comment: Great - so in the end we bot learned something! Thanks!